# how to check if an antivirus was deactivated or needing something to work properly

Tags: batch-file, cmd, antivirus

I wanna to know how can I check if an antivirus need anything like updating version or required update or needing license to work properly
just with CMD or Batch Script
thanks a lot

Comment: i think this should be asked on [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: what is differentiate between communities?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, SuperUser is for software questions.

Comment: what about script?

Comment: Scripting is programming, and don't let anyone ever tell you otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example  script that monitors the `productState` status and converts it into a variable. I managed to get it working with *my specific* AntiVirus, but your mileage might vary depending on which one your using.

I used the `productState` binary values from [here](http://mirum.weebly.com/redirect.html?url=http://neophob.com/2010/03/wmi-query-windows-securitycenter2/&auto=yes) but they can easily be changed by monitoring the values of `%byte1% %byte2% %byte3%` when your AntiVirus is *up-to-date*, *out-of-date* or *disabled*

```
@echo off
wmic /namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 path AntiVirusProduct get * /value|findstr "displayName productState"
echo.
set /p dec=Enter productState decimal value to detect state:
call cmd /c exit /b %dec%
set "hex=%=exitcode%"
set "hex=%hex:~2%"
set "byte1=%hex:~0,2%"&set "byte2=%hex:~2,2%"&set "byte3=%hex:~4,2%"
:: Check byte1
    set "status1=ANTIVIRUS"
    if "%byte1%"=="00" set "status1=NONE"
    if "%byte1%"=="01" set "status1=FIREWALL"
    if "%byte1%"=="02" set "status1=AUTOUPDATE_SETTINGS"
    if "%byte1%"=="04" set "status1=AVAST_ANTIVIRUS"
    if "%byte1%"=="08" set "status1=ANTISPYWARE"
    if "%byte1%"=="16" set "status1=INTERNET_SETTINGS"
    if "%byte1%"=="32" set "status1=USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL"
    if "%byte1%"=="64" set "status1=SERVICE"
:: Check byte2
    set "status2=UNKNOWN"
    if "%byte2%"=="16" set "status2=RUNNING"
:: Check byte2
    set "status3=UP-TO-DATE"
    if "%byte3%"=="16" set "status3=OUT-OF-DATE"
    if "%byte3%"=="32" set "status3=OUT-OF-DATE"
    if "%byte3%"=="52" set "status3=OUT-OF-DATE"
    if "%byte3%"=="58" set "status3=OUT-OF-DATE"

echo Type of antivirus  : %status1%
echo Scanning status    : %status2%
echo Virus definitions  : %status3%
echo %byte1%
pause
```

Of course you'll be better off using proprietary command line tools for specific AV's, but this should work.

Comment: your great sam, it work like a charm, thanks a lot for your great help